# preg_match issues after php upgrade

Tags: php, expression, match

I'm a total newbie when it comes to regular expressions. I'm getting errors being thrown back like this:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'a' in ...
```

I seem to get loads of these with different modifier values.

The code in question:

```
if (preg_match('/\.([^\.]*$)/' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$', $this->browser_languages[$i]) && isset($this->catalog_languages[$key])) {
```

I was informed by my server host that they had updated PHP to the latest version. This has probably caused the issue.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm guessing it just needs to be updated to run on the latest version of PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `/` as [pattern delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) so therefore everything after `/\.([^\.]*$)/` is treated as [pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (I guess `$value` starts with `a`).

I would switch to different delimiter (`~`) and used [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
preg_match('~\.([^\.]*$)/' . preg_quote( $value, '~') . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$~'
```

Also note the `~` at the end of the regexp.

Comment: Thanks that's fixed the issue. It's old code for a friend's website so I didn't want to tinker with it as I'm awful at regular expressions.